# emacs org mode: how to remove the trailing dot in a mean of hms values

Tags: org-mode

so i'm using vmean on a series of HMS values.  because I don't care about fractions of seconds i convert the hms value to seconds, floor that value and then cast back to HMS. Which works fine, however, I have been unable to figure out how to remove the trailing dot from the seconds field.

what I have:

```
@II .. @III = (0@ 15' 36", 0@ 16' 7", 0@ 16' 36", 0@ 17' 05")

0@ 16' 21." = @7$4 = hms(0,0,floor(deg(vmean(@II..@III))*3600))
```

what I want:

```
0@ 16' 21" = @7$4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a calc function that converts the seconds of an hms value to an integer:

```
(defmath hmsIntSecs (v)
  (let ((x v))
    (setq x (nreverse x))
    (setcar x (calcFunc-round (car x)))
    (setq x (nreverse x))
  )
)
```

Be sure to evaluate the function definition before proceeding.

What I get with just vmean:

```
| 0@ 16' 21." | 0@ 15' 36" | 0@ 16' 7" | 0@ 16' 36" | 0@ 17' 05" |
#+TBLFM: $1=vmean($2..$5)
```

Now what I get using hmsIntSecs:

```
| 0@ 16' 21" | 0@ 15' 36" | 0@ 16' 7" | 0@ 16' 36" | 0@ 17' 05" |
#+TBLFM: $1=hmsIntSecs(vmean($2..$5))
```